# How to attach Air208 GSM micro sim card board to raspberry pi zero w that already has display attached on GPIO

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, gsm

I have a Air208 GSM micro sim card board that I want to attach to my raspberry pi zero w to make calls.
The issue is that I already have a 3.5" tft display attached to the pi zero w via GPIO (header plus pins).

Is there I way I can still attach this GSM module?

Comment: You would need to look into both devices and see which pins they actually use. Obviously some can be shared like power and gnd, assuming the total current is within spec. For data lines it gets a little more complicated, If they are SPI, you may be able to use a different SS pin for each if you can alter the code to handle that.  If they are both I2C you should be fine to share the bus, as they will have different address. But you need to start with finding the actual schematics for both boards, or see if you can trace out connections to which pins on the pi are used.

Comment: Considering you said "make calls" this may not work either, but if an arduino could handle the GSM module work, you could do that, and then communicate with arduino via USB. Just another thought.